# Listview items and Image list items missmatching

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have created a image grid view using `ListView` and `ImageList`.. `image names` come from `database` and images are stored in `categories` folder. I adding images `imgList.Images.Add("", Image.FromFile(@"./categories/" + dr["image"]));`

but when program runs `1st` list view item not set to the correct image, `1st`listview`item` with `second image`, i think there is a indexing error. is something wrong with my code or any way to solve this?

```
private void LoadCategories() {
            DataTable categories;
            con = new Dbfunctions();
            con.MysqlQuery("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE online = 1");
            categories = con.QueryEx();

            //ImageList

            ImageList imgList = new ImageList();

            //CLEAR listview_Category items
            listView_Category.Items.Clear();

            //set listview category items as Large icons
            listView_Category.View = View.LargeIcon;

            //ADD image list into Listview
            listView_Category.LargeImageList = imgList;


            int i = 0;
            //ADD image into imagelist and Listview
            foreach(DataRow dr in categories.Rows){
                imgList.Images.Add("", Image.FromFile(@"./categories/" + dr["image"]));
                ListViewItem category = new ListViewItem();

                //bind listview item vwith image list item
                category.ImageIndex = i;

                //set Category name
                category.Text = dr["name"].ToString();

                //set font list items styles
                category.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Courier New", 15, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular);
                category.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(252, 119, 123);

                //ADD category items into Listview
                listView_Category.Items.Add(category);

                imgList.ImageSize = new Size(140, 140);
                imgList.ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth32Bit; 

                i++;
            }


        }
```

Comment: Looks ok. Are you __sure__ it mismatches??

Comment: yes,, 1st image does not load... second image comes 1st

Answer (score -1):

Please provide shapes of DB rows. Maybe you have a missmatch in DB so you call not proper index.

Comment: This is not an answer! Move to comment and delete!!

Comment: I can't comment yet (low reputation) and I'm willing to help the issuer.